# Calculate bounds of the sum of means of a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, bounds

*I am not sure whether this question really belongs on this StackExchange or whether I should post it on a different one. Please indicate if this is the case.*

I am programming an algorithm (A1) and I would like to get the bounds of a summation of means of a standard normal distribution. In formulas:

$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{b} \sum_{k=1}^b \delta_k $,

for a known $N$ (=10,000) and $b$ (=8), where $\delta_k$ is a matrix with all elements drawn from a standard normal distribution. All $\delta_k$ are sampled independently from each other.

I ran a simple simulation study to get an estimate and found the bounds to be roughly -150 and 150.

I would like to know whether there a way to get the upper and lower bounds using a theoretical approach?

EDIT:

I'll try to give some extra information to hopefully make the question more clear. The value resulting from the inner summation, $\frac{1}{b} \sum_{k=1}^b \delta_k$ is added to a certain matrix $x$ which is initialized at 0 and has the same dimension as $\delta_k$. This addition is done for a total of 10,000 times. For each update we check whether the new $x$ gives the optimal value. After doing this addition for 10,000 times the best value is saved.

I have a different algorithm (A2) that also tries to find the optimal value for $x$ and I want to compare both algorithms against each other. However, A2 requries bounds for $x$. My idea was to get the bounds from the formula used in A1 and use those as input for A2. I know that A1 will find the optimum. Thus, if I know the bounds on $x$ I can say with 100% certainty that the optimal value for $x$ is between those bounds and A2 should then try to find this value too.

Comment: Is this what you are doing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions?

Comment: The sum of means could be literally anything, so please tell us what you mean by "bounds."  The expression you give--assuming the $\delta_k$ are all independent--has about a 0.002% chance of lying beyond the interval $(-150,150).$ That's small enough that perhaps your simulations haven't yet detected this possibility: but it's real and a sufficiently large simulation will find it.

Comment: If "bounds" are theoretical means of max and mins of the 10K quantities, I could take a stab at the answer.

Comment: @whuber so with bounds I mean what the maximum and minimum value would ever be. I need these bounds to be inputted in a different algorithm which will try to find the optima between these bounds. So (-200, 200) will for sure be enough but I wanted to know if there was a nice theoretical justification to it. Also, how did you determine that there was a 0.002% chance of it laying outside the interval?

Comment: The distribution of your sum is Normal with mean $0$ and variance $10000/8.$  That determines the probabilities of any interval.  *Every* interval, no matter how far removed from zero, has some (albeit potentially astronomically small) probability.  Thus there are no bounds.  There are *practical* bounds in the sense that if you posit some probability $p,$ one can determine bounds $\pm L$ for which the chance that your sum lies beyond $[-L,L]$ is exactly $p.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you mean. I don't know if you read my edit on my post, but I don't think that changes your answer. I guess I'll just have to use the bounds found by my simulation with the side note that there is a small chance the optimal value lays outside this bounds

Comment: @user248463, check out the answer to math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables which has a formula for the expected max of a gaussian. In your case, you'd want the theoretical average of the max over 10K draws from an N(0, 1/8) distribution - the theoretical distribution of an average of 8 from a standard normal. The equation is a little gnarly; if your question gets reopened, I'll attempt to do the math.

Comment: @BenOgorek, thank you for the link to the other question and for offering to do the math. I am only not sure whether it is the same thing I am trying to achieve. I have a summation of 10K draw and want to find the max/min for that. It seems the other question does not contain a summation over the draws. With whuber stating that the distribution is normal with mean 0 and variance 10000/8 I can already construct a simple 99.99% confidence interval. This should do the trick in my opinion, unless I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @user248463, sure. I originally interpreted your question as, if you had 10K averages and you didn't want a single one to go over a bound, what values would you choose? Now I see that you have just one normally distributed variable after all the operations, so that's simple enough.